# Prove the identity $\binom{-x}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{x+k-1}{k}$ for complex number $x$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that for all complex numbers $x$ and all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$\binom{-x}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{x+k-1}{k}$$

The fact that we have a complex number in the identity confuses me, because I haven't worked with binomial coefficients using complex numbers.

**EDIT:**

$$\binom{-x}{k} = \frac{-x^{\underline{k}}}{k!} = \frac{-x(-x-1)(-x-2)\cdots(-x-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots1}$$

$$\binom{x+k-1}{k} = \frac{(x+k-1)^{\underline{k}}}{k!} = \frac{(x+k-1)(x+k-2)(x+k-3)\cdots(x+1)(x)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots1}$$

So, I can see that both of them are the same thing, except for the sign, which is flipped. I guess this is where $(-1)^k$ comes into play. Can someone help with the finalization of the actual proof? One more thing, if someone can give me an actual example with numbers where this identity holds, I would be glad. Cause, I don't know how can I compute it that $x$ is a complex number.

Comment: Write out $$\binom{x+k-1}k=\frac{(x+k-1)^{\underline k}}{k!}$$ and compare this with $\binom{-x}k$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you please check my edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see what’s happening in the numerator like this:

$$\begin{align*}
(-x)^{\underline n}&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-x-k)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(-x-n+1+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\big(-(x+n-1-j)\big)\\
&=(-1)^n\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(x+n-1-j)\\
&=(-1)^n(x+n-1)^{\underline n}\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $j=n-1-k$ in the second line. Thus,

$$\binom{-x}n=\frac{(-x)^{\underline n}}{n!}=\frac{(-1)^n(x+n-1)^{\underline n}}{n!}=(-1)^n\binom{x+n-1}n\;.$$

For a numerical example, let $x=i$ and $n=3$:

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{-i}3&=\frac{(-i)(-i-1)(-i-2)}{3!}\\
&=(-1)^3\cdot\frac{i(i+1)(i+2)}{3!}\\
&=-\frac16\left(i^3+3i^2+2i\right)\\
&=-\frac16(-i-3+2i)\\
&=\frac12-\frac16i\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
(-1)^3\binom{i+2}3&=-\frac{(i+2)(i+1)i}{3!}\\
&=-\frac16\left(i^3+3i^2+2i\right)\\
&=-\frac16(-i-3+2i)\\
&=\frac12-\frac16i\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How did you change the $k$ with $j$ in the product? I didn't exactly get that. But I see that it was the crucial step in the solution.

Comment: @terett: It’s just a substitution: set $j=n-1-k$, and automatically you have $k=n-1-j$, so that (for instance) $$-x-k=-x-(n-1-j)=-x-n+1+j=-(x+n-1-j)\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer. That was a neat trick with setting $j = n - 1 - k$. I never can thing of this stuff, maybe also because I always get confused about changing the indexes in summations and products.

Comment: @portal: You’re welcome. Sometimes it helps to write out a few terms to see what’s going on more clearly, though the details of the adjustments to the indices can still be a bit tricky.

Comment: Yes I see that it's a substitution, but doing this kind of random substitution is not a problem algebraically? Plus how can one come up with such substitutions?

Comment: @terett: Why should it be a problem? As with any substitution, it has to be carried out consistently throughout the expression, but that’s the only restriction. Coming up with this one is fairly straightforward. In one product the factors are increasing in magnitude with $k$, and in the other they’re decreasing in magnitude with $k$; to make them match, we have to reverse the order of the factors in one of the products. Since $k$ was running from $0$ to $n-1$, $(n-1)-k$ was running from $n-1$ down to $0$, and that’s exactly what we want.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the definition $ \displaystyle \binom \alpha k = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}$